# Get value of execution of a unix command in perl script

Tags: perl, unix, command, execute

I am executing a unix command through perl script to get size of a direcory.

```
$path = "/dir1/di2/";
system("du -sh $path");
```

How can I get the result back in my perl script.

I am using

```
$size = system("du -sh $path");
print $size
```

But it is giving size=0;

Comment: -1 This is a [Perl FAQ](http://faq.perl.org): [Why can't I get the output of a command with system()?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#Why-cant-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `system` call returns the status of the call, not the output.  Use backticks (or the `qx` operator) like:

```
$size = qx(du -sh $path);
```

Comment: Fails for paths with spaces. Fails particularly bad for paths named "`; rm -rf /`".

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this using `perl`, e.g. [as shown here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=168974). Something like

```
use File::Find;           
find(sub { $size += -s if -f $_ }, $path);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl syntax is very similar to Bash one. Backquote your command and it's output will be stored in the variable.

```
    my $variable = `command`;
    print $variable;
```

If your command has output on multiple lines, you can assign it to an array, for example:

```
    my @files = `ls -l`
    chomp @files;
```

Then, every output line will be stored in a different element of the array.

How to do a backquote may vary depending on your keyboard layout. On US layout it's the same key of tilde (~).

Answer (score 1):

It's returning the command status, which is success.

Instead, do:

```
$size = `du -sh $path`
```

(backquotes delimiting command)

Comment: Fails for paths with spaces. Fails particularly bad for paths named "`; rm -rf /`".

Answer (score 1):

Or you may redirect the output to a file handle and use it to get the output.

```
open (FD,"du -hs \"$path\" |");
while (<FD>) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/perl
$path = "/dir1/di2/";
print(qx(du -sh $path));
```

This should work !